# Task await fails

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, signalr, task

I am starting a HubConnection. First I get a new Instance of HubConnection, 
afterwards I create a new IHubProxy with Name = "fileHub" so far so good.

My problem is located at (or in) the awaitable Function ContinueWith, I try to start the Connection, and write to the console wheater the start was successful or not. 
The connection.Start() is successful and "Connected" is written to the console.
Code added after the Console.WriteLine("Connected") is executed without problems, too.

**But** the Task never finishes, so the Client Class calling the HandleSignalRAsync() Method waits for the completion unsuccessfully.

Adding a return; or task.dispose(); does not solve my issue.

```
 public static async Task HandleSignalRAsync()
            {
                connection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:12754");

                myHub = connection.CreateHubProxy("fileHub");

                await connection.Start().ContinueWith(
                    task => 
                    {
                        if (task.IsFaulted)
                        {
                            var ex = task.Exception.GetBaseException();
                            Console.WriteLine("There was an error opening the connection: {0}", ex);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Connected");                        
                        }
                    });

}
```

I call the Method with the TaskAwaiter in another Class of my Solution:

```
Functions.HandleSignalRAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

calling it with:

```
Functions.HandleSignalRAsync().Wait();
```

does not work, too.

Comment: Why do you use `ContinueWith` when you already use `await`? The code after `await` *is* a continuation. If you want to catch Exceptions, wrap the call in an exception handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But the Task never finishes

Because both examples synchronously block, causing your code to **deadlock**. You shouldn't be [blocking on async code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

You'll need to properly asynchronously wait on `HandleSignalRAsync`:

```
await Functions.HandleSignalRAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

If you're already using `async-await`, there's no advantage to use a continuation style with `ContinueWith`, you can simply wrap the execution in a `try-catch` statement and `await` inside:

```
try
{
    await connection.Start().ConfigureAwait(false);
    Console.WriteLine("Connected");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("There was an error opening the connection: {0}", e);
}
```